# How can local admin override policies for automatic updating?

Tags: group-policy, windows-update

Ì am local admin on my Win 7 computer. I want to prevent automatic updates that are controlled by group or domain policies. How do I do that? I saw this question about screen savers [How can I override group policy using a local administrator account?](https://serverfault.com/questions/65011/how-can-i-override-group-policy-using-a-local-administrator-account), I am looking for similarily detailed instructions for Windows Update. Something like `net stop wuauserv` (when I try this it is denied with an "error 5").

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: By philosophy and design votes are anonymous and **neither voting [up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) nor voting [down](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-down) requires any mandatory explanation**. The tooltip that appears when your mouse pointer hoovers over the down button states: *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. - My guess the downvotes are because our community is typically responsible for the enforcement of IT policies (not always thinking them up, though)  and your question is about circumventing those.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to disable updates on a specific system, just ask your IT department alter the scope of the policy enforcing it, or create an 'override' policy with a higher precedence. Your IT department does know about this, right? They likely has a very good reason for implementing managed system updates, including, but not limited to security, compliance, and support contracts - you shouldn't be altering these policies.

Comment: I don't care because I don't need to care about my IT departments policies. It would be better if you answered the question rather than moralizing about what I can and can not do.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be asking this question on serverfault. This site is intended for *professionals managing information technology systems in a business environment*, which you are clearly not. Flagged for migration to superuser.